# Triplet loss equivalent formulation

Tags: linear-algebra

In [*Rethinking Collaborative Metric Learning: Toward an Efficient Alternative Without Negative Sampling*](https://doi.org/10.1109/TPAMI.2022.3141095) ([open access version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.11549.pdf)), the authors assert the following:

$$
(\lambda + ||x - y||^2 - ||x - z||^2)^2 = (\lambda - 2x^\intercal(y - z))^2
$$

I'm relatively sure that:

- $\lambda$ is a constant
- $||x - y||^2 = (x - y)^\intercal(x - y)$
- $x$ and $y$ are distributed on a unit sphere

With that said, how do I prove the equality by transforming the left side so that it matches the right side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
&(\lambda + ||x - y||^2-||x-z||^2)^2 \\
&= (\lambda + (x-y)^\top(x-y) - (x-z)^\top(x-z)) && ||x - y||^2 = (x-y)^\top(x-y) \\
&= (\lambda + (x^\top x-2x^\top y + y^\top y) - (x^\top x-2x^\top z + z^\top z))^2 && (x-y)^\top(x-y) = x^\top x - 2x^\top y + y^\top y \\
&= (\lambda + x^\top x-2x^\top y + y^\top y - x^\top x+2x^\top z - z^\top z)^2 \\
&= (\lambda - 2x^\top y + y^\top y + 2x^\top z - z^\top z)^2 \\
&= (\lambda - 2x^\top y + 2x^\top z)^2 && \text{$y^\top y = z^\top z = 1 $ b.c. $||y||=||z||=1$} \\
&= (\lambda - 2x^\top(y-z))^2
\end{align}